# An idea for Insufficient info about removed users

Tags: feature-request

First of all i'd like to know what this is about: 
[image]

I think this is a very insufficient info.
In my opinion there should be some exceptions for each of these issues:

**1-** A user that you answered one of his/her question was removed.

**2-** A user that answered your question was removed.

**3-** A user that commented on your question was removed.

**4-** A user that upvoted one of your questions was removed.

**5-** A user that upvoted one of your answers was removed.

**6-** A user that upvoted one of your comments was removed.

and some other that can cause any rep changes.

Or at least there can be a better explanation such as "A user that up/down voted some of your questions/answers/comments was removed!"

Comment: -5 probably means that a user who upvoted one of your questions was removed. Anyway, I don't see how the information would be useful, you can't really do anything about it. Also the three cases you seemed concerned about wouldn't really appear in your reputation tab, none of these actions generate reputation for you.

Comment: What if it was a user that did all of the above on multiple of your posts?

Comment: @YannisRizos thank god some info that makes sense.

Comment: @Oded than those three will apper in a box with the rep change info! Shouldnt be so hard. If we can see the changes made in our posts which are more than 1 row in a box and the date of change in the same box this can be done either.

Comment: There's one entry for *all* the rep this user affected you by, so it could (and often is) "all of the above, and more".  You're talking about (in some cases) an incredible amount of information that we don't even store to be presented here, for little to no benefit...

Comment: @NickCraver cant you just create a small importance list? and when three of those occurs only the most important one should be shown.

Comment: Who cares about this information? Some points were lost because a user was deleted. Why is it important to know more?

Comment: @Pekka as i said its "insufficient" info. Cause when i see that i couldnt understand the reason as you can see. A person who cant see the meaning of an info is not supposed to be an idiot instead we should think that there is a lack of knowledge.. As i mentioned before this is just an idea. I dont really care about the rep change i care about the info "removed user" which doesnt mean anything to me its just like saying "a person just died".

Comment: @YannisRizos it doesnt matter if those examples up there are not collected the thing that im concerned about what this "User was removed" means come on anyone can see its not even close to understandable.. If a user was removed why am i seeing this info? what kind of relation i got with that user? if its not an important thing than why do we see it?

Comment: You say you want the information - but why would that be useful to you? So you will know the breakdown of the reputation loss. Great. Why is that so important?

Comment: @Oded Its important to have an information that makes sense! Instead of having some senseless words.

Comment: "User was removed" makes sense - ok, this could have better wording ("Reputation change due to deleted user" is too long and since the context is reputation change, simply using "User was removed", looks fine). A breakdown of lots points that you can't do anything about and can't action doesn't.

Comment: @Oded show me why "A user that up/down voted some of your questions/answers/comments was removed!" is not a better explanation than "User was removed" or "Reputation change due to deleted user" is not better than "User was removed". Just cause its long? Its nearly same! its not really a big change as word but a big change to make it more understandable..

Comment: @BerkerYüceer - again, that's an *insanely* (trust me) complicated thing to add for something you can't do anything about...it's simply not worth building or maintaining that.

Comment: @NickCraver I think he doesn't really want more details on the removed user, but a more [explanatory message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132487/an-idea-for-insufficient-info-about-removed-users#comment366668_132488)

Comment: It isn't better because there is absolutely nothing gained by the added information. What do you get by knowing the breakdown? Knowledge for knowledge sake in this case is silly.

Comment: @YannisRizos thanks! thats what i was trying to tell. also sorry about my bad english.

Comment: @YannisRizos - Look back history of the post, it seems the feature request is changing as I switch between other tasks here.

Comment: @NickCraver 
these options i gave makes sense and thats what i wanted to see. 
but you people told me there could be only 1 row as an explanation 
and i added another option as giving the same info with the options that i mentioned = "A user that **up/down voted** some of your **questions/answers/comments** was removed!" so this seemed more understandable to me.

Comment: Fair enough - a clarification like that might make sense. Removed downvote and turned it into an upvote.

Comment: @Pekka again im sorry about my english its a little more hard for me to explain my self. Cause english is my second language..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that message when the user that was removed had voted on one or more of your posts. You can't really make much sense of the score, -5 could for example mean that:

- The user had upvoted 5 of your questions, giving you 25 points,
- Then downvoted 20 of your questions, costing you 40 points, and
- Then upvoted 2 of your answers giving you 20 points.

The net gain for you from that user's votes is: 25 -40 +20 = +5, which you now lose since the user was removed. That's a total of 27 posts involved, and I don't think there's any value in knowing exactly what were the posts involved (or any other detail really), for the very simple reason that it's information you can't use. What are you going to do with it, other than satisfy your curiosity?

Comment: i guess im being rapidly misunderstood. I'd like to see an info that makes sense. When you say "a person died" what do you expect me to think? For that reason i said its insufficient and i would expect something like "a person you encountered before is died" and i would say "god forgive his/her sins".. This info could be given like "A user that up/down voted some of your questions/answers/comments was removed!" Thanks for the information anyway.

Comment: @BerkerYüceer, What more do you need? The message says exactly what it means. A user was removed, and it's therefore as if they were never there. That means all their votes go with them. It seems to me that what you're really saying is that you don't want to lose rep when a user is removed, and that's a whole different issue (which has been brought up amany times and is not likely to change).

Comment: @RivieraKid I think the `all their votes go with them` part was the source of the confusion, to be fair it's not documented anywhere.

Comment: @RivieraKid as YannisRizos mentioned i couldnt find any explanation about this thats why i wanted to put some more info there and if you read carefully i ve nothing to do with rep change.. i'm just trying to make this info more understandable.